# How to set class name in File and Code Template in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, templates

I want to define template once create new file or class in Kotlin in Android Studio look like:

```
/**
 *
 * FootballApp.kt
 *
 * Created by on 11/04/21 Android Studio
 *
 */
```

i've use the code as below:

```
/**
 *
 * ${FILE_NAME}
 *
 * Created by on 11/04/21 Android Studio
 *
 */
```

but once i use ${FILE_NAME} it always create file name but it miss .kt,
So anyone help me this problem

Answer (score 0):

`${FILE_NAME}` only returns the name of the file without extension.

As templates apply extension-wise, you can append `.kt` to it, for it to be included in the file.

```
/**
 *
 * ${FILE_NAME}.kt
 *
 * Created by on 11/04/21 Android Studio
 *
 */
```